# Chained typedef : Perf. issue?

Tags: c++, typedef

Working with new pieces of code, I asked myself a question : **Are multiple typedef's over the same basetype impacting performances ?**

Example (I know it's silly but that's what I actually saw, four levels of typedef...) :

```
typedef float T_FLOAT
typedef T_FLOAT T_TIME
typedef T_TIME T_CURRENTTIME
tyoedef T_CURRENTTIME CLOCKCURRENTTIME
// etc.
```

The application I'm working with is quite huge (hundreds of thousands LoC) so I'm wondering...

Using -02 (sometimes -03) with GCC, is it computing every of these 4 types to the basetype ?

Any heads-up appreciated =)

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, typedef is a compile time only option.

Comment: Do you mean typedef is "replacing" every subtype with the basetype ?

Comment: @Isaac Clarke: there is no basetype and subtype. `typedef` just creates a new name for an existing type, it doesn't create a new type (7.1.3/1). So the compiler always knows everything it needs to know: there's no reason that the typedef should have any affect on the emitted code, compared with just using `float`.

Comment: Thanks ! That was easy, but worth asking.

Answer (score 4):

The runtime overhead of `typedef` is exactly zero. It just defines synonyms. In your example, you can see that mixing `CLOCKCURRENTTIME` and `float` for the same variable, for instance, is accepted without problems by your compiler.

EDIT: An example of what I mean

```
// MyFunction.h

void MyFunction(float f);

// MyFunction.cpp

void MyFunction(CLOCKCURRENTTIME f)
{
  // Do whatever
}
```

The declaration and the implementation match because `float` and `CLOCKCURRENTTIME` are completely interchangeable for the compiler. If they were just convertible, you would be creating a new (unrelated) function in the .cpp file.

Comment: You're right, i actually wrote : printf("%f", CLOCKCURRENTTIME).

Comment: I've added an example to clarify a bit what I mean.